# Metabox is not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, save-post

Any idea, how I would get this to save? I have several select boxes that are done with the standard option statement. This one has me stumped on how to get it to save.

```
<p>
<?php
    $options = get_option( 'name' );

    $names = explode( PHP_EOL, $options );
    ?>


    <label for="title" class="timeshare-row-title"><?php _e( 'Property Name:', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></label>
    <select name="Name">
    <?php foreach ( $names as $name ) {
        printf(
            '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
            $name,
            $name
        );
    } ?>

    </select>
```

Updated Section:

```
function timeshare_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'timeshare_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'timeshare_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

// Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
// Checks for input and saves if needed
if( isset( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'name', $_POST[ 'name' ] );
```

}

Comment: Can you show up *how* you're saving your metadata? I'm assuming it's in the [`save_post` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I added the extra code you requested.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure $_POST keeps case but try changing `name` to `Name` with a capital `N`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee not a winner, I think it has something to do with no selected() bieng included but I have not found were it would go.

Comment: I don't see where you're creating your nonce nor where you're getting your post meta. Looks like you're using `get_option()` instead of [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I have an Options page with a group of Text Areas allowing input. Then those lists are grabbed and create the select box list for choices. My nonces statement is in the beginning of this file. The file is quite large so I did not post the entire file.

Comment: So where is your save failing? Which conditional? When you print out `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true )` it returns `FALSE`?

Comment: You gave me a thought so I did some digging. My values are being saved to the DB but it is not reflecting on the metabox screen.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You gave me a thought so I did some digging. My values are being saved to the DB but it is not reflecting on the metabox screen.

Comment: Because youre not using the get_post_meta function

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I guess I am just not seeing the fix. Where would get_post_meta function be placed? My other meta boxes work its just this one that draws from the options page?

Comment: Post Meta is saved in the post meta table, not the options table. [See metabox tutorial - Step 4](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I understand that but perhaps I was not clear. I get options is used to populate the drop down list for the select box. It is literally providing the options to choose from. I have several Metaboxes on this page, most done based on the exact tutorial you sent me. it just so happens that this is a special case. I needed the values to be populated from a list that was entered on the Options(Settings) page for the plugin. I do appreciate your assistance, I am a poor communicator.

Comment: Right, but you are then saving the selected option as **Postmeta** so then you need to use the get_post_meta() funtion to retrieve and show you selected and saved value. You've already verified its being saved to the database.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee See I thought since it is a select box I had to use the selected() function. I have tried adding selected to the statement but I have not figured out the correct syntax. Based in the metabox tutorial you sent me, select boxes use the select() function.

Comment: All the select fucntuion does is compare two values and if the two values are true printed out the attribute "selected" which tells our html which option is selected. You still need to pass two values to the select function, one being a value from your foreach loop and the othet being the saved value from get_post_meta -https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I realized after the fact that I do have a e get_post_meta function, it is at the top of the file. I have read through all the tutorials you have sent me and none of them reference how to use the current meta data with the for each loop. I have tried several different methods and still to no avail am I able to get the current value to show. In my other select boxes I am using an IsSet statement with a select statement that is straight forward. The part that has me messed up is the for each and how to integrate the IsSet statement with this. Each time I try it breaks the page.